# Dual Avelyn build

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was playing Dark Souls 2 and I got deeply in love with the crossbow Avelyn. I got it from a secret door in the Undead Crypt. Since crossbows can be wielded single-handedly, I was thinking of a dual Avelyn build. So will I be able to obtain the Avelyn again if I burned a Bonfire Ascetic at the Undead Crypt?

I've also seen an YouTube video depicting the above build so either this must be possible or there must be another way.

I'm playing the base game not the Scholar of the First Sin edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Avelyn is found in a metal chest and Bonfire Ascetics don't reset those. The only way to get a second Avelyn from this chest is in NG+ or you could have another player drop one for you online.

Another way to get more Avelyns is in the Doors of Pharros area (Brightstone Cove Tserolda in SotFS), by killing the red phantom [Bowman Guthry](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/bowman-guthry), who only appears if you play offline and can repeatedly be killed by using Bonfire Ascetics.

Comment: What about Bowman Guthry?

Comment: @SlayerDiAngelo You are right, sorry. I never played the game offline so never came across the phantom and didn't think of it. I changed the answer.

Comment: Anyway, the drop rate is so low in case of Bowman Guthry.